# Fill Letters converted to Mesh objects with top faces removed with objects

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, physics, transparency

I am using Blender 2.90.0 on OS X Catalina

I would like to fill up glass letters (letter object converted to mesh) with objects (actually spheres, but  used a cube to test.

I removed the top faces to allow an opening (naive of me, I know) and let the cube fall, but it bounces before it hits the opening as if there is face there.

I figure I could probably get the same affect using some sort of bounding box, but I would like to  try this using Physics.  the cube is an active object, the letter  is passive.  I have tried active for letter as  well.

I assume there has to be an "official" way of telling blender that the face isn't there...

[image: Bouncing box should fall in but doesn't]

Comment: Leave the letter as passive and change it's setting from 'Convex Hull' to 'Mesh'.  That should do it. (not on the big machine so can't be more precise).  If it doesn't, try using the solidify modifier on it to give it's walls a little thickness.

Answer (score 1):

This was my own error.

The Collisions shape for the letter was correct as well as the shape for the falling particle.  HOWEVER, I neglected to sett he shape for the backdrop, and the object was interacting with its "convex hull" shape before it got to the letter.

Now it works beautifully